# Can't find element by class selenium amazon

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently trying Selenium Webdriver on the amazon.es webpage. I have successfully navigated through the webpage, looking for an element by class (the search item button to be precise).

The problem is when I try to get the prices of the webpage. The webpage can be found [here](https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/261-8047486-3232562?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Balon%20Baloncesto&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3ABalon%20Baloncesto) (just look for Balon Baloncesto=> Basketball). When I try to search the element by class, this one exactly:

```
<span class="a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold">EUR 33,64</span>
```

Selenium cannot find it, giving the not found element error. Here is the Java implementation. `nav` is the browser object.

```
//value = a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold
elemList = nav.findElements(By.className(value));
//elemList appears to be empty after this
```

There are not any iFrames on the webpage which can affect me, so I do not get very well where can the problem come from. Any help would be appreciate it.

Best regards

Comment: Please post the actual error message. I'm guessing it's not element not found if you are using the entire class inside `By.className()`. If you did that, you would get something along the lines of "Compound class names not permitted" which is basically stating that you are searching for more than one classname inside of a locator that takes only one classname.

Comment: The error what I get is element not found, not the other one that you mention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`By.className(value)` has specific behavior for elements with multiple classes. I can't find this behavior documented in the JS bindings, but here's an excerpt from the same functionality in Java.

[From the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#className-java.lang.String-):

> If an element has multiple classes, then this will match against each of them. For example, if the value is "one two onone", then the class names "one" and "two" will match.

So when the actual class attribute is `class="a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold"` only the following `By.className` identifiers would match.

```
By.className("a-size-base")
By.className("a-color-price")
By.className("s-price")
By.className("a-text-bold")
```

Be warned however that I would expect one or more of these to additionally identify some other objects on the screen that you don't want.

If you want to match on **ALL** of the classes, try using an xpath which checks if the `@class` attribute contains your value.

Alternatively (and this will typically perform better than xpath) use a css selector that chains all of the class names together. Each class name in a CSS selector should be preceded by a `.`

```
By.css(".a-size-base.a-color-price.s-price.a-text-bold")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have this is consideration for the future.

Answer (score 1):

This code might help you:

```
WebDriver nav = new FirefoxDriver();
nav.get("https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/261-8047486-3232562?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Balon+Baloncesto&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3ABalon+Baloncesto");

 List<WebElement> elements = nav.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold')]"));
 for(WebElement element: elements) {
         System.out.println(element.getText());
  }
```

Comment: It works but Brian's answer is more complete and gives an explanation about the mistake I was doing, anyway thank you very much for your response!!

Comment: Yes, it is. I agree with you. Thanks for the feedback.